# When to use C++11 mutex, lock, unique_lock, shared_lock, etc

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

1. What is the difference between `shared_lock` and `shared_mutex.lock_shared()` other than that the destructor of `shared_lock` unlocks the associated mutex?
2. Is a `shared_mutex` the only mutex class I can use with `shared_lock`?
3. Why would someone want to use `lock_guard` instead of `unique_lock`?
4. If I have many threads constantly locking for reading (`shared_lock`) a variable and I have a variable that tries to lock it for writing (`unique_lock`), will this writing thread have a priority over the other ones?
5. For #4, is there a possibility for a deadlock?

Comment: Always prefer RAII to explicit release operations. Otherwise, use the simplest one that provides the functionality that you need, so you don't pay for what you don't need.

Comment: By RAII, you mean enclosing my locked code with braces? Ex:
{
   lock;
   foo = ...;
   // Destructor will unlock
}

Comment: No and yes. The lock classes fulfill the RAII requirement of locking something and automatically unlocking once the lock's destructor is called. With mutexes, you have to unlock them explicitly.

Comment: [C++ Concurrency In Action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1933988770)  by Anthony Williams would be a good start.

Comment: On the mutex's page, the example now uses lock_guard

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I finally understand the RAII idiom (at least the basics), but there are still some questions that I couldn't find any answer.

Answer (score 9):

1. `shared_mutex.lock_shared()` is a function call that locks `shared_mutex` in a shared mode, while `shared_lock` is a "lock-class" that is used to lock and automatically unlock mutex at the end of the scope.
2. No, you can use `shared_lock` with any type that meets the [SharedMutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SharedMutex) requirements.
3. Always use `lock_guard` unless you need additional functionality of `unique_lock`. This way your intent is more clear.
4. This does not depend on `shared_lock` or `unique_lock`, but on what `SharedMutex` you are using. Exact beheavior is not specified by the standard. But here are some clues:

   - On Windows `shared_lock` will usually be implemented using `SRWLOCK` and  tries to be fair e.g. will try to balance readers and writers. No one will have higher priority here.
   - On POSIX systems `shared_mutex` will most likely be implemented on top of `pthread_rwlock_t` and implementations usually give preference to readers because of its requirement to support recursive read locks.
   - Boost `shared_mutex` tries to be fair and gives no preference to either side.
5. With reader-preferring `shared_mutex` it is possible for your writer thread to never acquire the lock if there is always at least one reader holding it.