# What's the difference between unique_lock and shared_lock in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Trying to understand when one might use `shared_lock` over `unique_lock` or vice versa. The C++ doc is very cryptic! I'm aware that the general guideline is to use `lock_guard` over the two if we desire immediate, scoped (or RAII) mutual exclusion.

Does this have something to do with `condition_variable`? I've seen all three being used with this if I recall correct.

I've seen a question on stack overflow that is similar but avoids answering this question here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770500/when-to-use-c11-mutex-lock-unique-lock-shared-lock-etc#:~:text=lock_shared()%20is%20a%20function,the%20end%20of%20the%20scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770500/when-to-use-c11-mutex-lock-unique-lock-shared-lock-etc#:%7E:text=lock_shared()%20is%20a%20function,the%20end%20of%20the%20scope).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its pretty simple, really.  `unique_lock` calls `lock()` on the mutex.  `shared_lock` calls `shared_lock()`.

The difference between them is that `shared_lock` is designed to support readers in a read/write lock.  You  can have multiple threads all acquire the shared lock and reading the same data, but if anyone wants to write to the data, they need to use `lock` to get permission to write to the data.

Which one you should use depends on the pattern you are looking for.  There are plenty of times where a read/write lock is desired (which is why the standard includes support for them).  There are also times where a simple unique mutex is called for.  In general, if reading and writing are meaningful concepts to you, there's a decent chance that a read/write mutex like `shared_timed_mutex` is the right approach.